# StackOverflowError on recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, bukkit, stack-overflow

I get a StackOverflowError when using a recursive method. I am building on top of the Spigot API.

This is my method:

```
private Location spawnPlayer(Player p) {
    int r = new Random().nextInt(ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().size());
    final Spawn s = ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().get(r);

    if (s.hasPlayer()) {
        spawnPlayer(p);
    } else {
        s.setPlayer(p);

        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Arsenal.p, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                spawnClear--;

                if (spawnClear == 0) {
                    s.setPlayer(null);
                }
            }
        }, 0L, 20L);
    }
    return s.getLocation();
}
```

I get the error at `spawnPlayer(p)`, which calls itself if the spawn already has a player.

Comment: We've no idea what `ServerManager` is? What it's `getInstance()` method gives. What exactly is `Spawn`, what is `Bukket`? Well, there are so many unknowns in that code.

Comment: @RohitJain I believe that's a minecraft server mod (mod framework?).

Comment: I would advise against creating a new `Random` instance in each call to the method, though I don't think it's the cause of the infinite recursion. Try to create a single `Random` instance outside the method and store it in a member of your class.

Comment: Sorry for that, Bukkit is a API for Minecraft servers.

Comment: Alas, they had one stackexchange site per Java exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `s.hasPlayer()` is always true, making it so:

```
if(s.hasPlayer()){
    spawnPlayer(p);
}
```

gets executed inside of the `spawnPlayer(Player)` method, which therefor causes the method to run infinitely, causing the [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

To fix this, you could wait before calling `spawnPlayer(p)`:

```
if(s.hasPlayer()){
    long timeToWait = 20L;//set the time to wait to 20 ticks (1 second)
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(Arsenal.p, new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            spawnPlayer(p);
        }
    },timeToWait);
}
```

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
private Location spawnPlayer(Player p) {
    int r = new Random().nextInt(ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().size());
    final Spawn s = ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().get(r);

    if(s.hasPlayer()){
        long timeToWait = 20L;//set the time to wait to 20 ticks (1 second)
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(Arsenal.p, new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                spawnPlayer(p);
            }
         },timeToWait);
    }
    else{
        s.setPlayer(p);

        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Arsenal.p, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                spawnClear--;

                if (spawnClear == 0) {
                    s.setPlayer(null);
                }
            }
        }, 0L, 20L);
    }
    return s.getLocation();
}
```

Another fix would to make it so `s.hasPlayer()` is not always true, for example, by using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to make sure the player wasn't already spawned:

```
List<String> spawned = new ArrayList<String>();

private Location spawnPlayer(Player p){
   int r = new Random().nextInt(ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().size());
   final Spawn s = ServerManager.getInstance().getServer(p).getSpawns().get(r);

   if(s.hasPlayer() && !spawned.contains(p.getName()){
      spawned.add(p.getName());
      spawnPlayer(p);
   }
   else{
     //the rest of your code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. When the game begins, the player is being assigned to a spawn and is removed immediately afterwards, which means hasPlayer returns null. I just want to avoid players spawning on the same spawn point in the map.

Comment: In that case, you could just make a List of all of the already used spawns, and then only spawn them in a spawn if that location isn't in the List.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to create an ArrayList of the not-used spawns and pick a random spawn from that. Then, I will re-add the spawn after three seconds and set the player to null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but logically I think you want:

```
if (!s.hasPlayer()) {
    spawnPlayer(p);
```

Note the !.

In general though, take a lot of care with recursive funcitons in minecraft :)  Once I wrote one that would turn a tree into logs but it ended up recursing over leaves--the explosion was quite spectacular--wiped out the entire forrest and killed my client because of all the activity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I however want to re-execute the method if the spawn has no player, so a new random is generated.